# SVG pattern being fuzzy when using a mask

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

Chrome doesn't render the following svg example like Firefox or IE 10:

```
<svg style="width: 500px; height:500px">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern-stripe" width="4" height="4" 
         patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
            <rect width="2" height="4" fill="white"></rect>
        </pattern>

        <pattern id="pattern-stripe2" width="4" height="4"
         patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
            <rect width="2" height="4" fill="green"></rect>
        </pattern>
        <mask id="mask-stripe">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" 
                  fill="url(#pattern-stripe)"></rect>
        </mask>      
    </defs>
    <!-- When there is no scale, you can't see the problem. -->
    <g transform="scale(4,4)">
        <!-- First square:
             Use mask, fill attribute is specified on the element.
         -->
        <rect style="mask: url('#mask-stripe'); fill: green;"
              x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"></rect>
        <!-- Second square:
             Use the second pattern. The fill color value need to be set on
             the pattern. You can't reuse the hatch pattern with different color
         -->
        <rect style="fill: url(#pattern-stripe2);" 
              x="51" y="0" width="50" height="50" ></rect>
    </g> 
</svg>
```

The first square is fuzzy in Chrome while being properly rendered in Firefox or in IE 10. The cool thing about the first square is that the pattern color can be controlled by css directly on the `rect` element which is using the mask. So if I have many squares, I can reuse the pattern and apply different colors for each.

Whereas in the second case, you have to apply the color on the pattern which makes it less reusable as you can't change the background color for a specific square.

Here's is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LZdw/2/) with the above example.

**Question:**

Is there anything that can be done to fix the problem in Chrome?

Or maybe another solution that still use css styling over the element to control the 'fill' attribute?

**Notes:**

- I can't remove the `transform` attribute from the `g` element. And it plays a role here: if your remove the scale in the transform you can zoom with your browser and you'll never see anything fuzzy.

  In my real scenario, I need to be able of using the `transform` as I'm using `path` elements. Scaling manually the values with javascript would be too slow.
- I partially solve my solution (in case it might help someone else):

  If you have a maximum scale value for the transform, you can scale all your data with that maximum value then applying the inverse of your current scale. That is instead of

  ```
  <g transform="scale(currentscale, currentscale)"> (conceptually)
  ```

  You do:

  ```
  <g transform="scale(1/currentscale, 1/currentscale)">
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following solution meets your needs?

First, surround your object with another `<g>` and apply the mask to that.

```
<g mask="url(#mask-stripe)">
    <g transform="scale(4,4)">

        <rect style="fill: rgb(0, 128, 0);" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"/>

    </g>
</g>
```

Then add a scale to your `patternTransform`:

```
<pattern id="pattern-stripe" width="4" height="4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
         patternTransform="scale(4,4) rotate(45)">
    <rect width="2" height="4" transform="translate(0,0)" fill="white"></rect>
</pattern>
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2LZdw/6/)

Comment: Your solution is really interesting! Only small drawback, you have to group the elements which use the same pattern in the same group. But this is something I can handle in my code. Thank you very much!